# In Mysql Perpared statement increase the set variable length

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

```
    set @sql1 = '';

    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(IF(field_id = ''',
          field_id,
          ''', value, NULL)) AS `',
          field_id,'`'
        )
      ) INTO @sql1
    FROM content_details;
    SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT  ', @sql1, ' FROM content_details GROUP BY content_id');
    select @sql1;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

In above code @sql1 variable storing some limited characters only. 
Here I am concating string dynamically. 
I donot know the exact total length of the string what will come future. my question is how we can set the unlimited char length to the $sql1 variable. Please advice.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In that I need $sql1 variable with unlimited char length.

Comment: Please add this to the body of your question, so that we do not need to go through the comments to know what the actual question is. Have you encountered any problem so far? The maximum size for a variable is so large that I wouldn't even bother thinking about it.

Comment: Yes. I have problem with length of the character stroing. It is not storing all the characters. storing some limited (255 something) characters only.

Comment: The limit, if such limit exists, is much higher than that (see with a plain `SET @a = 'blahblah....'`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you are having an issue with the [`GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). You can adjust the length of this variable during your session.

The default length of this variable is 1024.  You should be able to use:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = yourNewValue;
```

If you were to set this globally it would impact all other connections, that is why you might only want to set it for your session.